# Ajax POST To .Net Core MVC Controller Can't get the right parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a ViewModel looks like

```
namespace HealthBox_WebCore_V1.ViewModel
{
    public class ProductViewModel
    {                
        public MST_ProductViewModel MST { get; set; }
        public List<int> FoodsID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I have a ajax function like this

```
function post() {
       /* var url = $("#CreateProductForm").attr("action");*/
        var data = $("#CreateProductForm").serialize();                
        var FoodsIDVal = [];
        $("select[name='FoodsID']").each(function () {
            var values = $(this).val();
            FoodsIDVal.push(values);
        });
        var ViewModel = {
            "MST":data,
            "FoodsID":FoodsIDVal
        };        
        console.log(ViewModel);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "CreateProduct",
            data: JSON.stringify(ViewModel),
            dataType: "json",   
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
    }
```

If I use this way, I get this result in Controller

[image]
[image]

FoodsID get null.

But if I use this,

```
function post() {
       /* var url = $("#CreateProductForm").attr("action");*/
        var data = $("#CreateProductForm").serialize();                
        var FoodsIDVal = [];
        $("select[name='FoodsID']").each(function () {
            var values = $(this).val();
            FoodsIDVal.push(values);
        });
        var ViewModel = {
            MST:data,
            FoodsID:FoodsIDVal
        };        
        console.log(VM);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "CreateProduct",
            data: ViewModel,
            dataType: "json",     
            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
    }
```

here is the result in controller
[image]

I just want to post these two object to Controller 『MST and FoodsID』
I also try add attr [FromBody] or other way as I can search in Google,
but can't find a way to slove this problem.
Please help, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add `[FromBody]` to the action and use the first ajax,here is a demo:

action

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateProduct([FromBody]ProductViewModel productViewModel) 
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

ajax:

```
function post() {
       /* var url = $("#CreateProductForm").attr("action");*/
        var data = $("#CreateProductForm").serialize();                
        var FoodsIDVal = [];
        $("select[name='FoodsID']").each(function () {
            var values = $(this).val();
            FoodsIDVal.push(values);
        });
        var ViewModel = {
            "MST":data,
            "FoodsID":FoodsIDVal
        };        
        console.log(ViewModel);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "CreateProduct",
            data: JSON.stringify(ViewModel),
            dataType: "json",   
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
    }
```

If you still cannot get FoodsID,try to check the data of `FoodsIDVal` in ajax.